# "Dynamic" data in an asp-for=""

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a form and within that form I want to create 4 contacts. In stead of creating a partial view for each contact, I want to create one partial view "to rule them all".

example:

```
public class FormViewModel
{
  public string A {get;set;}
  public string B {get;set;}
  public ContactViewModel ContactC {get;set;}
  public ContactViewModel ContactD {get;set;}
  public ContactViewModel ContactE {get;set;}
  public ContactViewModel ContactF {get;set;}
}

public class ContactViewModel
{
  public string ContactType {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

And I have a ContactCreatePartial with as model: ContactViewModel.

In this partial I want to create an input for the "FirstName" of ContactC.
Normally I would use:

```
<input asp-for="FirstName">
```

But, because I want to reuse the partial, the value I need to put in the "asp-for" is dynamic:

```
<input asp-for="@(Model.ContactType).FirstName">
```

With as output: for="ContactC.FirstName" and id="ContactC_FirstName". Unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there a way this will work?

I know I can write out all html, but that way I also have to write out my validation etc. If it is possible, I want to auto-generate my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your partial via:

```
<partial name="_ContactPartial" for="ContactC" />
```

Then, inside the partial:

```
@model ContactViewModel

<input asp-for="FirstName" />
<!-- etc -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do with a series of if, since an n object can be dynamic

```
@if (Model.ContactType == "ContactC"){
    <input asp-for="ContactC.FirstName" id="ContactC_FirstName">
}else if(Model.ContactType == "ContactB"){
    <input asp-for="ContactB.FirstName" id="ContactB_FirstName">
}
```

Edit:

Using the data provided in the problem and in the statement I came up with the following solution

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" id="@(Model.ContactType)_FirstName">
```

I would use the id as parameter to decide on what to store if that is the case, since the id yes, can be dynamic

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my partial uses 'ContactViewModel', so it doesn't know 'ContactC.FirstName', it knows 'FirstName'. Second, I would rather create 4 different partials in stead of the if/else statements, for readability

Comment: in this case I think I have a simpler solution, I will edit the answer